# Convert m3u8 url to only one ts url in java

Tags: java, m3u8

Sorry if this question is already answer, but i have searched in weeks but no solution as my expected.

I have a m3u8 url, now I want to convert it to only one ts url (without downloading anything), I can get list of ts url inside that m3u8 url, but no idea about combining them into one.

Here is my example m3u8 url: http://cdn18.nofree.keeng.net/s2-kfilm/adaptive/20180719/bf8a429/playlist.m3u8

Comment: Given the example file, what would be the expected result?

Comment: @jpw like this: http://cdn18.nofree.keeng.net/s2-kfilm/adaptive/20180719/bf8a429/playlist_1080.ts
I can get just list ts url: playlist_10801.ts, playlist_10802.ts,...

Comment: I still don't quite get what you mean by "combining them into one". They are different urls, so what should the output be. Also, do you want the output to be written to a file or something, or just construct a new url for further processing?

Comment: @jpw I want a new ts url that can play all sub ts url content without download anything, is that possible?

Comment: I don't see how you could play the content without downloading anything, and the urls contained in the file seem to be for different qualities of the same content.

Comment: Yes, it has different qualities and i can get list ts url for each quality. I dont want to download because I just need url to cast video to TV.